# How to make inheritance template in Pyrocms?

Tags: codeigniter, template-engine, dwoo

Pyrocms is using Dwoo template engine.

In Dwoo, we can make inheritance template.
{extends "default.html"}'

but, I can't do this in pyrocms that using Dwoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wouldn't work. We only use Dwoo to allow dynamic syntax in the themes and written content.

What are you trying to achieve? The idea is you make multiple layouts and any shared content is put into partials, then you can load them using {theme_view('partialname')}

All of that stuff is a bit of a mess in v0.9.9.7, we've cleaned up the themes and syntax a LOT for v1.0 :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got the idea.